# Function that checks if all vowels in a string are capital letters

Tags: haskell

```
Check::String->Bool
Check = undefined
```

I can use only list comprehension and I can use only Base Functions and Library functions. I know how to do it recursively only, like this:

```
charfound::Char->String->Bool
charFound c(x:xs) | c==x=True
                  |otherwise=charFoundc XS
```

Comment: How would the recursive solution look? How would the list comprehension be different?

Comment: @Josh Lee I would make a function that search all the vowels in a string, something like: charfound::Char->String->Bool   charFound c(x:xs)  | c==x=True |otherwise=charFoundc XS

Comment: @ Josh Lee  But I'm not an Haskell expert..I've just started to learn. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`notElem`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/notElem_f.html), and [`all`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/all_f.html), like this:

```
check :: String -> Bool
check = all (\e -> e `notElem` ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
```

Here is an explanation:

- `(\e -> e notElem ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])` is a function that takes `e`, and returns whether it is not an element of the lowercase vowels.
- `all` takes a. a predicate that transforms elements to booleans, and b. an array of these elements, and returns whether the predicate is true for all elements of the array.

Another thing that might help is to note that this is written using [point-free notation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree), but it is equivalent to

```
check s = all (\e -> e `notElem` ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']) s
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand what this does :

Comment: @Madalina Added and explanation

Comment: @Madalina Try to literally read the code (and I don't mean that in a rude way). Reading it plainly from left to right, it says "all e's are not elements of a list of vowels".

Comment: @Carcigenicate It seems to me an equivalent formulation, though, no? If there are no lowercase vowels, then, by definition, all vowels are uppercase (including the case that this is  trivially true, since there are none).

Comment: @AmiTavory Nvm, I think you're right. Sorry, tired :/

Comment: @Madalina He's right, this would do what you want. If there aren't any lowercase vowels in the string, all the vowels must be uppercase. I didn't think it through thoroughly when I posted my other comment.

Comment: @AmiTavory the snippet is only half-pointfree, since it has `e`. The pointfree version would be some line noise along the lines of `check = all $ flip notElem "aeiou"`.